# Time-series Clustering

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis

I am trying to achieve this kind of segmentation/clustering. Is there any Python package that can do the job? [image: Periodic Time Series Wave]

Comment: `y` value of your timeseries can only take values `1`, `0.5` and  `0` .?

Comment: yes, it is just a sample of a periodic time-series data

Comment: So, if you are sure you will only have these three values in the timeseries, why don't you simply use a `if` statement to map the points accordingly.?

Answer (score 1):

Try tslearn package: https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
You will find sufficient documentation to follow the process of timeseries clustering